# how can I set and initialize an imageview in a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, expandablelistview

I am trying to set and initialize an imageView in a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter . I understand that the findviewbyid method is only for activities so in this case how do I go about it . This is what I have and as expected its giving me a cool error

```
ImageView arrowImageView = convertView.findViewById<ImageView> (R.id.group_header_arrow);
```

Comment: can u please tell us what u actually want to do?plz elaborate..!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see looking in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)), the findViewById isn't a generics method. The method always return a View object and you should cast it to your desired object type. The correct code for you would be:

```
ImageView arrowImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.group_header_arrow);
```